# OCR tool for handwritten mathematical notes

Tags: ocr

I have a pdf of 100+ handwritten pages that I need to convert to machine readable text. So far I have tried tesseract and a free online tool with no success. The output seems to be jibberish.

```
tesseract myscan.png out -l eng
```

I've attached one example page. It contains both text, mathematical symbols (eg. integral sign) and occasionally pictures.

[image]

Maybe I'm using tesseract wrong? Could anyone try and get a decent output off this?

Comment: What you ask for is the entire complex field of computer vision and interpretation. It isn't simple and there are no quick answers. This is why companies spend years and millions of dollars working on these tools. If the handwriting can't be recognized, either find a tool that can recognize it or build a tool specific to this handwriting.

Comment: I should have mentioned that when I used the OCR tool in onenote (which this document was created on) it did seem to give sensible outputs. I'm not expecting an exact conversion, just to have atleast bits and pieces that have a sensible output.

Answer (score 0):

I use http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-ocr-software.htm
Watch out for the installer trying to load you up with other stuff
When it works, it just gives you bits to copy and paste.
But don't rush to download this one, try your's again first.

The problem likely isn't with the software, it's probably your input.

Scan at 600 dpi.
Try to increase the contrast and sharpen the image. The thinner and more defined from the background that the letters are, and the clearer the interspacing of the loops are, the better your chance of OCR capture.

These adjustments are best made in your original scanning software. 8MP or better camera can also make the scan.

Use GIMP to tweak after the scan.